# What available multiplatform languages are there available for 2D games

Tags: 2d, cross-platform

I was wondering what multi-platform languages are available that could be used to create and deploy 2D games, please note that im not asking which is the best as I do not want to cause arguments over which people believe to be the best.

Ideally I would like to be able to deploy to as many different platforms as I can (PC, Mac, iPhone, Android, etc..)

I do apologies if this has been bought up, but I could not find anything from the searches that I tried.

Comment: Question is rather general, why don't you at least mention some platforms or groups of that you interested? Mobile, Consoles, Desktops.

Comment: Well my aim was to be a bit more general though I will make an edit so that it clears it up a bit more

Comment: Check out this question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6975/what-tools-should-i-consider-if-my-aim-is-to-make-a-game-available-to-as-many-pl?rq=1

Comment: Any language is multiplatform so long as a compiler has been written for your target platforms.  The fact that you're asking this question suggests that you're relatively new to this, so I'm going to make my usual recommendation which is that for a first project you're biting off far more than you can chew by trying to hit so many platforms.  Focus on one for the purposes of learning, then expand out for subsequent projects.

Comment: As is this question isn't a problem that needs to be solved but simply going to provide a list of answers (which may eventually be out of date).

Answer (score 4):

- You could also use HTML5 Canvas element and JavaScript (or languages compiled to JavaScript, such as [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), [Dart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_%28programming_language%29), ClojureScript, TypeScript, [CoffeeScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript)). While not specifically created for games, it's suitable. You can deploy your project on Macs, Linux, Windows, Android, iOS.
- Flash with [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript#ActionScript_3.0): it used to be standard de-facto for games for web in mid 2000, it's still supported on mobile platforms via Adobe AIR. Macs, Windows, Android, iOS.
- [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29), used a lot in game industry for utility and scripting, but there is number of frameworks, with [Corona SDK](http://www.coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/) or [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/)
- [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) is supported almost everywhere except iOS, you should be able to deliver your product (unless you use esoteric bindings) on Linux, Windows, iOS, Android. [Libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) – Is pretty mature framework that supports Android, Windows, Mac OS, Linux and Web. Alternatively, you don't have to use Java, but can use [Scala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29), [Clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure) or [Groovy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_%28programming_language%29) [etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) (or any combination of those) and deploy to JVM.
- [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29)/[C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) Simply standard de-facto, works everywhere except web. While there is ways to compile C/C++ code to JavaScript and AVM (Flash Player bytecode) I would advise against it. C/C++ is probably most popular languages when we talk about console games.
- [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) with MonoGame an Evolution / rewrite of XNA that allows you to port one code base to many platforms. Alternatively, you can look into Unity platform.

There is good reasons for and against each one of them. C/C++ would open to a world of bigger tripple a games if you choose to pursue this carrier. HTML5/JavaScript, Corona/Lua and Flash/ActionScript will allow you to start implementing game really quickly, and rather easy languages to code. Java I guess somewhere in a middle, but it will require full rewrite if you choose to deploy your application on iOS.

Comment: For Lua, there is [Löve](https://love2d.org/) too.

Comment: Python with [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/) is very multiplatform as well, albeit not for mobile devices.

Comment: @Mokosha could you edit my post and add pygame with some notes if any, I'm not familiar with python or it's frameworks.