# Write a 2d game that is portable to mobile, browsers and computers?

Tags: porting

I would like to develop some 2D and 2D Isometric games. Anything ranging from Tetris to Terraria style games. My problem is that if I develop said game for a PC user, I want to be able to port it web browsers and mobile platforms, and easily. And by easy, I mean I want to develop something which can run in all 3. Perhaps I can isolate the gaming logic, graphics and input logic too. But I don't want to rewrite major components. So I will need to work with an engine that runs on all of those, or at least 2 out of 3 (mobile, computer, browser). I considered Java applets but for some reason those are the most unpopular method for playing online web games. There are just so many decent flash games, the only applet based game I can think of is runecraft and that is pretty old.

Comment: HTML5+JavaScript

Comment: Heheh... game.html  ...although being serious, would html5+js be able to handle lighting, and with decent enough frame response times?

Comment: Welcome to the site. This kind of question does not facilitate the Q&A format. For information about what kinds of questions to ask, feel free to visit the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Please, entertain me... how is porting not faciliating Q&A? The only problem I see here is smug people pushing those who don't understand as much about game dev around. Sorry if me being here offends the real game devs like you!

Comment: @Zombies, I was serious. WebGL can do all the 3D you want and a Canvas in 2D context can do all the 2D you want. :)

Comment: @Zombies It's not Q/A because it just produces a list of responses, without one being more correct than the next. That means there's no *correct answer* to this question. That leaves out the Answer part of Question and Answer. See the [FAQ] about "Which technology to use" questions. If you feel it's a bogus rule, feel free to post about it in [meta].

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6975/what-tools-should-i-consider-if-my-aim-is-to-make-a-game-available-to-as-many-pl

Comment: Java is virtually available everywhere.

Comment: One of the features of my library is exactly what you request. It is open-source, however it is not finished yet, it is a ongoing work. If that doesn't stop you, feel free to start using it and ill support new features and fixes and provide help when possible.
https://github.com/DevilWithin/Nephilim

Answer (score 5):

My standard advice to anyone who asks this question (or similar) is: **DON'T**.

You're starting out, you want to make a first game, you're making the engine yourself, *by definition you have no idea what you are doing*.

You need to learn so so much; how to structure a game loop, how to handle timing, how to handle input, networking, sound, display, possibly networking, communication between a client and server, storing and update of game states.

On top of that you *also* want to run it on multiple platforms for which a considerable proportion of this functionality is going to range from being completely different to having weird corner cases and gotchas that need to be handled.

Forget it.  *You have enough to be getting on with in the first batch of stuff you need to learn*.  Adding multiple platform support *on top of that* is going to spread yourself too thin.

Now, there's absolutely nothing wrong with supporting multiple platforms; it's a great thing, but your job right now is not to support multiple platforms, it's to learn the basics of how to build a game.  So focus on one thing at a time, assimilate it, then move onto to the next, because taking on all of this together is too much.

So, for the first game, pick a single platform, learn how to set things up properly and get them working on that.  Once you know how to handle input, timing, networking, whatever properly on a single platform, *then* you can go and port it.

Otherwise take the (IMO good) advice in the other answer and forget about the engine, use something like Unity that handles all of that stuff for you (somebody else has suffered so you don't have to) and focus on the game itself.

Answer (score 1):

Unity of course.
With it you can develop games on: Windows, Linux, Mobiles and Web.
Have a look at http://unity3d.com/learn.
Hope it can help you.

Comment: -1 This is little more than just a link answer. It should be a comment.

Answer (score -1):

With Libgdx you can write your game once and share it to Windows, Android, Web, Mac.
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Comment: -1 This is little more than just a link answer. It should be a comment.